# Error reporting from Flex app

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a Flex 3 app which I want to instrument to report errors generated by the app to a server via simple HTTPService call.

My idea is to wrap all the methods in try ... catch blocks which then pass the Error object to the reportError() function (which then fires off the HTTP request and pops up a dialog) but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a system such as the one you suggest, wrapping all of my methods in try/catch and sending the stack trace to a service that emails me the errors. I created a basic format for the error that logs which method the error occurred in. I noticed that sometimes I end up getting null from the stack traces, so I wanted to log that information for these situations.

It GREATLY improved my application. I tracked down a (large) handful of errors and released a much cleaner build to my users. Now I don't ever get the emails.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing too. I only wish it could catch all the bugs. Maybe there's a screen-capture program for Flash? ;)

Answer (score 1):

The better way IMO is something like [this](http://code.google.com/p/log4as3/).
I've no idea how good is this particular project (aside from this spooky GPL license), but I don't see why logging in action script should be any different from J2EE, C++, or say Python. Yes, it has some sand box security issues, but I think if this solved, you could log into some centralized log server..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there really isn't -- errors don't bubble up in such a way as to be trappable at a global level, so the only real way you have to catch errors is to try and catch them all manually.  (The community's been pretty vocal in asking for a global exception-handling feature for a while, but it's not there yet.)